# How to allow $user variable in a blade view page in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this page support.blade.php in views folder and I'm using Laravel.

I can't echo out `$user->id` or `$user[id]` in this page and I get undefined variable error. It's possible to echo it out in other pages, like in tickets.blade.php but in this specific page it's not working.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the data first from controller method:

```
return view('support', ['user' => $user]);
```

If you want to display ID of an authenticated user, you can do this from any part of the app without passing data from controller method:

```
{{ auth()->user()->id }}
```

Comment: Sorry where is form controller located?

Comment: @nima I mean from a controller method. Like from `public function index()` method.

Comment: When i add {{ auth()->user()->id }} i get Trying to get property of non-object error

Comment: @nima you can do that only for an authenticated user. Login and try again.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the logged in user id or username

Answer (score 1):

Within your Service Provider you can use

`View::share('key', 'value')`

You can consult the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) for a more indepth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you pass data in view file??

```
return view('support', ['user' => $user]);
```